# How to get Hostname in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to save my client's name in related database on `SQL Server`, and i don't want received it by parameter even i want to insert from stored-procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another good approach would be using `sp_who2` system procedure like below. Checkout for the `login`, `hostname`, `dbname` and `command` column.

```
exec sp_who2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Rahul

Comment: I'm not seeing any advantage of using an undocumented stored procedure that then has to be inserted into somewhere and filtered over using the function?

Answer (score 5):

my problem was solved by using below code in stored-procedure.

```
SELECT HOST_NAME()
```

Comment: Note that the host name can be specified in the connection string (i.e. spoofed).

Comment: @AiyoubAmini Are you sure you want SELECT HOST_NAME() and not SELECT @@servername ?

Comment: @gsharp I mean the name of the client computer. Don't make mistakes.